# TypeScript error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number | ""'

Tags: typescript

I'm new to TypeScript and I'm having a hard time understanding the following error.

```
Type '{ order: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'TestType[]'.
  Type '{ order: string; }' is not assignable to type 'TestType'.
    Types of property 'order' are incompatible.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number | ""'.
```

This is my test code

```
export enum ACTION_TYPES {
    TEST_ACTION = 'TEST_ACTION',
}


export type TestType = {
    order: number | '';
};

export function TestAction(
    testTypes: TestType[]
): {
    type: ACTION_TYPES.TEST_ACTION;
    testTypes: TestType[];
} {
    return {
        type: ACTION_TYPES.TEST_ACTION,
        testTypes,
    };
}

export type PluginsState = {
    testTypes: TestType[];
};

export type Actions =
    | ReturnType< typeof TestAction >;



const reducer = (
    state: PluginsState = {
        testTypes: [],
    },
    payload?: Actions
): PluginsState => {
    if ( payload && 'type' in payload ) {
        switch ( payload.type ) {
            case ACTION_TYPES.TEST_ACTION:
                return {
                    ...state,
                    testTypes: payload.testTypes,
                };
        }
    }
    return state;
};

export const stub = [
    {
        order: '',
    }
];


const defaultState: PluginsState = {
    testTypes: [],
};


reducer( defaultState, {
    type: ACTION_TYPES.TEST_ACTION,
    testTypes: stub,
} );
```

and this is TypeScript playground [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwIIGEAqBJAeQDkB9HATQAUBRAZTgG8AoASBzpxO32LgF44Acna1O3QkUEAaJgF8mC0JFhwYATzDA4OYAGcYODVoHMW0ACbAoALjgpUAIytwAPkMEBuOV6ZLo8ADNkRABjGABLCERtPRgMMMjEAApWGFjDTV1bHX0M4ABtAF0mAEpbU3VNW3FiMio6ADoRMVwJLxY03KMsmK7NIq9ZRlYoYBhkKGjTDqNq1tqKGlomji55ohkWDvTuzdlBxXB-VSM4SgAbZABzcMRdWhgAQzT+Ye2+vWyd-sLBnz8VJUtPEIlFdPxWG4AEpjCaIPIAHhOmggAV6cQSUTgAD4fAoQmD4KNzMgQs4BCkWPpnsBbBdrrd7k8XiZWO8DN1bEU9pswI81OcII9zAB+aqYu6lOmXG53B40-jYt7hNFJOB8gVC8xwABkOqEQMEcFu6v5guFcBKbypAHdwjAQgALOBqjXm8wNIGW60sEKPXTA9Z1JYrURrHhEaxsrajcaTH1bBpJ6lpTZbLadDmZWxurWe756NNbfZs+QsMuxuFwFPAP6HZTwAl3eD6ZAOV75VjTCxWWyCaSseS-BRMJv6OCWAKPZDnGDytLShly5nGN6ZvI9bneEfE0lWNWT6ez+fAKRr2aYIOLRrNcMSTbrznV8YOGRDEpeIA)

The error comes from the last line `testTypes: stub`

I'm pretty sure there is something I'm doing wrong, but I'm not understanding why `''` cannot be used with `number | ""`

Is there a workaround to this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have written is correct from an author of the code perspective, this should be working fine. But, here is how Typescript sees it (rather, inferences it):

```ts
export const stub = [
    {
        order: '',
    }
];
```

This is essentially, of type: `{order:string}[]`, which makes sense in *most of the cases*. However, this is a generalized version of your `{order:''}[]` so, Typescript cannot guarantee that whatever is passed is going to be `{order: number|''}`, you may mutate it and Typescript will still have to allow it. So, it warns you.

To avoid this inferencing you can do two things:

1. Explicitly assign the type to `stub` as `TestType` so that TypeScript can error out when it is no more of that type, like this:

   ```ts
   export const stub: TestType[] = [
     {
       order: "",
     },
   ] ;
   ```
2. Or, perform a [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) on the mutable array elements promising that element is unchanging like this:

   ```ts
   export const stub = [
     {
       order: "",
     } as const,
   ] ;
   ```

Here is your working example: https://tsplay.dev/WvpdYN

Comment: Thank you so much (again) for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
export const stub = [
    {
        order: ''
    }
];
```

the compiler has to *infer* the type of `stub`.  There are all kinds of types that it *could* be (such as [`unknown`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown) or [`any`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) or `Array<object>`, etc).  So the compiler uses heuristic rules to pick what it thinks is most appropriate.  In the above case, the type inferred is:

```
/* const stub: Array<{order: string}> */
```

That's an unordered array of objects which must have an `order` property of type `string`.  That's `string`, and not the [`string` literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `""`.  Inferring `string` instead of `""` is often exactly what people want in declarations like this: string-valued properties are often changed later:

```
stub[0].order = "somethingElse"; // okay
```

But unfortunately, that's not the type you wanted.  When you later try to use it in as part of an argument you pass to `reducer()`, the compiler sees `{order: string}` as not assignable to `TestType`, and you get an error.

---

In order to fix this you need to either explicitly [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) `stub`'s type to what you want:

```
export const stub: Array<TestType> = [ // annotated
    { order: '' }
]; 

reducer(defaultState, {
    type: ACTION_TYPES.TEST_ACTION,
    testTypes: stub, // okay
});
```

or you need to change how the value is inferred by the compiler, possibly by using a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to keep `""` as a string literal:

```
export const stub = [
    {
        order: '' as const, // const assertion
    }
];
/* const stub: Array<{ order: ""; } */

reducer(defaultState, {
    type: ACTION_TYPES.TEST_ACTION,
    testTypes: stub,
});
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwIIGEAqBJAeQDkB9HATQAUBRAZTgG8AoASBzpxO32LgF44Acna1O3QkUEAaJgF8mC0JFhwYATzDA4OYAGcYODVoHMW0ACbAoALjgpUAIytwAPkMEBuOV6ZLo8ADNkRABjGABLCERtPRgMMMjEAApWGFjDTV1bHX0M4ABtAF0mAEpbU3VNW3FiMio6ADoRMVwJLxY03KMsmK7NIq9ZRlYoYBhkKGjTDqNq1tqKGlomji55ohkWDvTuzdlBxXB-VSM4SgAbZABzcMRdWhgAQzT+Ye2+vWyd-sLBnz8VJUtPEIlFdPxWG4AEpjCaIPIAHiBEACvTiCSiAD4fAoQmD4KNzMgQs4BCkWPpnsBbBdrrd7k8XiZWO8DN1bEU9pswI81OcII9zAB+aoYu6lGmXG53B5U-iYt7hVFJHl8gXmOAAMk1QiBgjgtzgqv5gpKbwpAHdwjAQgALOAq3km8wNIFm6YsEKPXTA9Z1JYrURrHhEawsrajcaTc1bFgNeOUtKbWOsvI9Y3q13fPTJrb7FnyFiFyNwuCJ4B-XH4uCWAKPZDnGCytKSukyxnGN6dNmZDmFGT5w7KeB4u7wfTIBwABle+VY0wsVlsgkErHkvyYAHoAFRwUf6MvjafVKBQXkIhiLmyHqC3K6yBXbzcKCfT-JTwoNK+vABEuggqBjLad7UOcPo-h4cCbpucAQAA1ryCiEsSVhJLW9aNs2wBSF2syYH6iyNM0wYSJs3ZprYr5Tjh0EIKe0AAIRyCU-xHCo+7jkeACMJ5nmoCI5D2wAKgIc4sAwsFQJY14rnA65eMhJJQGhwB1g2TYdjhFR4TUpCEcsxG6WR2Y9K+XE0TB8GIbILEKEOxwcYek6zvOLJXsu+renu+J7EwG47t5Y5OQ4vHnhJ7lwD+EFyXAT5IcARJKSpamYZpuFVPhIb+kRqxGakJmUUeA62QoQA)